# Is there any way at all to create my own anchors in an answer

Tags: discussion, edits, markdown, hyperlinks

After writing a very long answer (as the initial answer was producing lots of questions), I wanted to add a table of contents to ease browsing the answer. But I was unable to create HTML anchors for the various sections. Is there any way to do that. The anchors I created by editing were simply erased when I posted.

I did read several questions, and their answers, about anchoring. But, at best, I just got a vague negative feeling.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to fill an answer with custom anchors.

If each part *can make an independent answer*, I'd recommend splitting your answer in multiple answers. In this way, you can have anchors to every part.

[Example of such an idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions.) (But in this case it the question itself is a table of contents - you could add a tldr in your first answer and place the contents)

But if each part would really be just a part and not a viable answer by itself, there is *really* no way to create links to each part.

Comment: Splitting an answer into multiple answers just for the sake of being able to use anchors is a very bad idea. Most of the FAQs that utilize this method only do so because all the content is too long to fit into one answer. Doing this on a normal site would likely just result in all but one of them being deleted, and having it all merged into one, because it *is* one answer.

Comment: @ani Yes, but I noted: "if each part can make a relatively independent answer".

Comment: I don't think "relatively independent answer" is an accurate representation. The only time you should be posting multiple answers is if they are completely different (completely independent) answers. If they are related to each other, they should be together.

Comment: @ani :) ok, let it be more accurate.

Comment: Thanks for trying ...  Too bad the suggestion to do it for titles and subtitles was not followed.  Seemed a simple idea, without any risk of anchor conflict.

Comment: @babou As I seem to have answered your question,  you can accept it :) Linked question is the request to implement it.